# What features of iOS 7 are available to iPhone 4S users?

Tags: iphone, ios

What features from iOS 7 are available on the iPhone 4S? Is it any more sluggish that iOS 6?

Comment: FWIW, I think answers to the "sluggish" question would necessarily be opinion-based.  That said, I personally haven't found it any less performant.  Maybe a little nicer in some areas.

Answer (score 6):

[TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2013/06/10/ios-7-phases-out-the-iphone-3gs-and-the-original-ipad-some-feat/) posted this breakdown of new features and the devices upon which they will work when iOS 7 was announced:

> Panorama -- The photo feature Apple introduced last year will be
>   available on the iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, and fifth-gen iPod touch. iPad
>   users are out of luck here.
>
> Square/Video formats and swipe to capture -- These features will be
>   available on the iPhone 4 and above, the third-generation iPad and
>   above, the iPad mini and the fifth-generation iPod touch.
>
> Filters in Camera - This Instagram-inspired feature will only be
>   available for the iPhone 5 and the fifth-generation iPod touch.
>
> Filters in Photos - This will be available on the iPhone 4 and above,
>   the third-generation iPad and above, the iPad mini and the
>   fifth-generation iPod touch.
>
> AirDrop - AirDrop in iOS 7 will only work on the iPhone 5, the
>   fourth-generation iPad, the iPad mini and the iPod touch.
>
> Siri - Siri in iOS 7 has new voices, a new interface and a whole lot
>   more functionality. Users trying to take advantage of the latest and
>   greatest from Siri can run it on the iPhone 4S and above, the iPad
>   with Retina display, the iPad mini and the fifth-generation iPod
>   touch.
>
> iTunes Radio - Apple's long-rumored music streaming and recommendation
>   service will run on any iOS 7-compatible device.

Since this announcement, Camera filters were added to the iPhone 4S as well.

The iPhone 4, iPod Touch 5th Gen, and iPad 2 and up models fully support Control Center, Notification Center, and Multitasking.

EDIT: Here's a helpful chart posted by [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/the-prettiest-way-to-find-out-what-ios-7-features-your-512905905):

[image]

Comment: just to add to this, everything in iOS 7 is backwards compatible 1 year, so the 4S and 5 will both have all the iOS 7 features as the 5S, minus of course the fingerprint identifier.

Comment: @samrap I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say. The 4S doesn't have AirDrop, for example, though (as I stated) it did gain Camera filters.

Comment: @zigg my mistake I thought I had put airdrop in there obviously if it requires new hardware it won't work, is what I was trying to say